# Display RSS Feed in iPhone`

Tags: iphone, ios, rss

I have a list of `RSS` feeds and I need to display the detail of each feed in iPhone. I got all `RSS` feeds from the server  which I'm displaying in tableview. Now on selecting a row I need to display the discription of `RSS` Feed which is coming from Server in `HTML` content like:-

`<a href=\"http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/articleshow/4881843.cms\"><img border=\"0\" hspace=\"10\" align=\"left\" style=\"margin-top:3px;margin-right:5px;\" src=\"http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/photo/4881843.cms\" /></a>Cadila Pharmaceutical will seek the govt's nod in two days for initiating clinical trials for a vaccine against swine flu.<img width='1' height='1' src='http://timesofindia.feedsportal.com/c/33039/f/533968/s/1f181b11/mf.gif' border='0'/><div class='mf-viral'><table border='0'><tr><td valign='middle'><a href=\"http://share.feedsportal.com/viral/sendEmail.cfm?lang=en&title=Cadila+to+apply+for+clinical+trials+for+swine+flu+vaccine&link=http%3A%2F%2Ftimesofindia.indiatimes.com%2Farticleshow%2F4881843.cms\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"http://res3.feedsportal.com/images/emailthis2.gif\" border=\"0\" /></a></td><td valign='middle'><a href=\"http://res.feedsportal.com/viral/bookmark.cfm?title=Cadila+to+apply+for+clinical+trials+for+swine+flu+vaccine&link=http%3A%2F%2Ftimesofindia.indiatimes.com%2Farticleshow%2F4881843.cms\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"http://res3.feedsportal.com/images/bookmark.gif\" border=\"0\" /></a></td></tr></table></div><br/><br/><a href=\"http://da.feedsportal.com/r/133515347892/u/0/f/533968/c/33039/s/1f181b11/a2.htm\"><img src=\"http://da.feedsportal.com/r/133515347892/u/0/f/533968/c/33039/s/1f181b11/a2.img\" border=\"0\"/></a><img width=\"1\" height=\"1\" src=\"http://pi.feedsportal.com/r/133515347892/u/0/f/533968/c/33039/s/1f181b11/a2t.img\" border=\"0\"/>`

How do I display this `HTML` Content in our iPhone `UI`, as this will contain text,hyperlink and images.

Is it proper way to use `UIWebview` in this case, as `UIWebView` is heavy weight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like below.

first of all

```
 descLbl.text=[self flattenHTML:descLbl.text];//descLbl.text is a text in which you are getting that HTML description...
```

now in flattenHTML method write like below...

```
   - (NSString *)flattenHTML:(NSString *)html {

NSScanner *thescanner;
NSString *text = nil;

thescanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:html];

while ([thescanner isAtEnd] == NO) {

    [thescanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:NULL];

    // find end of tag
    [thescanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:&text];

     html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n"] withString:@" "];
    // replace the found tag with a space
    //(you can filter multi-spaces out later if you wish)
    html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@>", text] withString:@" "];

} // while //

return html;

 }
```

let me know it is working or not..

Happy coding!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Please read this blog : **http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial**, 
 It is useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to show `HTML` entities as it is, i would suggest to go with `UIWebView`. You can pass this `HTML` as a string in method `loadHTMLString:`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to view the content as a web page, then loading the url in `UIWebView` is the best and easiest way.
Like this:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
NSURL *pageurl = [NSURL URLWithString:http://www.google.com];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pageurl];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [RSSKit](https://github.com/H2CO3/RSSKit) library.